# How i can add the group by sql in aspx.vb

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

IN SQL:

```
select SE.shipperId, SUM(SEDetail.totalSize) as CBM from SE, SEDetail
where SEDetail.shipperId=10011 and SE.id = SEDetail.bolId and SEDetail.containerId
between 1 and 5 group by SE.shipperID
```

I had change that and this work in aspx.vb:

```
SELECT SE.shipperID as 'Shipper ID', SUM(SEDetail.totalSize) as CBM 
FROM SE inner join SEDetail on SE.id = SEDetail.bolId and SEDetail.containerId 
between 1 and 5 Where
```

But I have error when I add the `group by` in the sql:

```
SELECT SE.shipperID as 'Shipper ID', SUM(SEDetail.totalSize) as CBM 
FROM SE inner join SEDetail on SE.id = SEDetail.bolId and SEDetail.containerId 
between 1 and 5 Where group by SE.shipperID
```

How can I use that in one sql?

Comment: remove Where from             between 1 and 5 Where and you should be through

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `WHERE`

```
SELECT SE.shipperID as 'Shipper ID', SUM(SEDetail.totalSize) as CBM 
FROM SE inner join SEDetail on SE.id = SEDetail.bolId WHERE SEDetail.containerId 
between 1 and 5 group by SE.shipperID
```

Comment: When i delete the where, the error is Incorrect syntax near 'SE'.

Comment: see the updated answer...I have removed the "and" condition by WHERE clause

Comment: I also can not use that in aspx.vb, now the error is Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Why you cannot write that ...can you show some of your code snippet that how you are preparing query..

Comment: Dim str As String =  ""   i still cam dp not it ><